# Undirectional many to many in Java

Tags: java, many-to-many

I made a UML diagram and started my code but i don't know how to present undirectional many to many relationship in my java code . As I looked for it I found that in this situation I need to create an arrayList but the issue here is I don't know if I should create 2 arrayLists in both client class and hotel class (shown in the picture) or just one arrayliste in client.

I have to mention that this one is an exercise so i can't change the uml diagram.

Any ideas ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47MiY.png]

Comment: This is unclear. Can you clarify a bit ?

Comment: Well . The problem here is how to write in code the relationship between class Hotel and Client as shown in the picture . Client here can reserve many time and so on the hotel can have many client but the arrow in the relationship there is saying that hotel shouldn't have an inctence of client (undirectionnel relationship) so I'm confused how to apply all that in my code .And to mention that I can't use SQl in this situation just arrayLists or victor